# WPF: How to replace the default MainWindow.xaml.cs and MainWindow.xaml files?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

This is a common problem:

I find an XAML pair on the Internet, one which does exactly what I need. I was able to "Add Existing Item" so both pairs are recognized.

To complicate matters further, the original file's signature looks as customary:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

but the newcomer (rectangleexample) has a different signature:

```
public partial class RectangleExample : Page
{
    public RectangleExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I had to comment out the second `InitializeComponent()` because it is not found.

Is there a straightforward way (ie, without complicated surgery) to accomplish this?

Update:

I did a full copy (of the newcomer file) on the existent XAML. I removed the old MainWindow pair and renamed the new ones. This is the only remaining problem:

`The name InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context`

I tried to find a "Add Existent Item", looking for a XAML pair, but such option is not there.

Comment: just rename the namespaceand control

Comment: if you comment `InitializeComponent();` your program wont run

Comment: `your program wont run` Of course! I know. I was trying to see whether it builds (it does).

Answer (score 0):

Look for Initialize component trough all the files in the solution, it is defined in a partial class, so you have to rename that class as well.